# Simulating from a vector of discrete data

Tags: r

I have a vector of discrete data and I want to simulate from the empirical distribution associated to this data, I was simulating with the function rlogspline after doing fit<-logspline(vector_of_data) where vector_of_data is data that is suppose to be coming from a continuous distribution, that's why I used logspline, but with this vector I have the certainty that the values in it are of discrete nature so I can't use logspline to adjust a "fit" for it.

Basically what I want to do is to adjust a "fit" of the observed data and then use that fit to simulate those values. Do you think this can be done in R?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can't just apply round() to the simulations you get from logspline?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but the problem is if I have a vector of only positive discrete values I could end up with a simulation that gives me negative values, because of the way the spline is calculated around 0.

Comment: No. You have not looked at the second and third arguments to logspline carefully enough.

Comment: You are completely right, overlooked that argument, I'll try it then :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `sample(x,...,replace=TRUE)` (sampling with replacement) should simulate from the empirical distribution ...

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that it will return me values that I've already observed, I would like to have values from the "real" density that haven't been observed already and that could be observed once I have adjusted the density.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally clear exactly what you are trying to do, but could you use something like `quantile` and `runif`, for example:

```
obs <- c(125,110,115,100,150)             # original observations
sim <- quantile(obs, runif(10000))        # simulations
hist(sim, freq=FALSE)
```

[image: sim histogram]